# Adding Microdata to a website of company listings

Tags: seo, microdata

Let's say you have a website that is akin to the YellowPages. It is a listing of lots of other companies.

Should you place microdata about each company on each company listing page? Or should you just put Microdata about the "Yellow Pages"?

For example:

```
http://www.lots-o-companies.com/supplier/joes-florists
```

Do I put all the Microdata on the page to be about Joe's Florists, or the parent website, Lots O' Companies?

I'm not quite sure how Google wants this data? On a site level, or a page content level?

Comment: Have you checked to see what mark up your competitors are using for their markup?

Comment: One of the most important lessons I learned working in a startup is never assume your competitors are right. If you ever get to see how they work on the inside, you generally discover they have no idea either.

Comment: One of the most important lessons in SEO is finding out how your competitors are ranking in the top 10. You then use this information to make your own improved version and with any corrections required long the way. Additionally you should note that there's little to none evidence to support that markup directly will increase your rankings, I thought I'd mention that since you've tagged SEO and Microdata.

Comment: @bybe It's a mistake to assume that your competitors are following best practices just because they're ranked higher than you. There's LOTS of factors that go into your ranking, and copying something poorly implemented because you *think* that's helped them, when actually it's lots of inbound links, or something else that's helped them, is a huge mistake. You should NEVER blindly copy something without understanding what you're doing.

Comment: I never suggested to blindly copy them, I was implying that you take a look and use what is good and improve on whats not good. In a lot of niches the top ranking websites have millions spent on SEO and a lot of time can be saved by reverse engineering their links, markup and lots of other things. Unless, were talking about a lot traffic niche then ya most likely best to ignore. Again, not suggesting you do this, or copy them like for like! but ya I think you get what I mean even if you disagree ;)

Comment: My point is that you cannot tell how your competitors are ranking in the top 10 (as you put it) by just looking at their public code. For example, I remember one of our top ranking competitors had *tens of thousands* of entries in one sitemap file, which went against every recommendation by search engines at the time (and may still do). The chances are they were ranked highly due to other factors *in spite of* (rather than *because of*) their messy sitemap.

Comment: Even with regards to huge companies I would *still* be cautious about assuming they've done everything as well as they could. External linking factors a lot more into your SEO rankings than anything you can do onsite! That said, the real Yellow Pages actually use Microdata on a per company level, just as closetnoc reasons they should... So maybe I'll mirror that, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you want the mark-up for your pages most important content. Would it pay to have your companies mark-up one each page? I do not think so.

Think of the person who is searching looking for information about *joes florist*. They want to know about Joe, where he is located, what is the phone number, what is he offering, etc. This is exactly what mark-up is for.

However, on your company pages, I would take advantage of mark-up for your company. I would make sure this was available on as many pages as is appropriate. For articles, assuming that your site may have a few, then you want to mark-up those pages with mark-up appropriate for an article.

Use mark-up to benefit the user first, the company second.